# Login with Facebook for iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook, ios6

I have application that is already running on iOS 5 as well as iOS 6. Now for next step I want to implement functionality of "Login with Facebook".

My application already has login authentication so the facebook login will be additional one.I knew that iOS 6 has provided new framework for facebook but I have two questions:

1. How do I implement this facebook functionality, so that it should work on both iOS 5 and iOS 6 devices?
   2.How do I maintain session with facebook login?

Comment: HI.. did you get the right answer.. i need  this  @iMash

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1) Follow these steps for facebook login instructions: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login-with-facebook-using-ios-sdk/

2) Once you implement the above using facebook sdk 3.x, this will also work for iOS 5 and iOS 6.

Comment: what about ios 9 objective-c

Answer (score 4):

First of all we have to add this frameworks in our projects,

[image]

after that you can import this methods in appDelegate

```
 #import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>
 #import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
```

after that didFinishLaunchingWithOptions we have to add this method

```
[[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                         didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
```

you can call Callback Methods,

```
#pragma mark - Callback methods
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation    {
return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application openURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation];
}
```

after that in your facebooklogin action method we have to write,

```
FBSDKLoginManager *loginManager = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
        [loginManager logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile", @"email"] fromViewController:self handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
            //TODO: process error or result.
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"Process error");
                [self facebookLoginFailed:YES];
            } else if (result.isCancelled) {
                [self facebookLoginFailed:NO];
            } else {
                if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
                    NSLog(@"Token is available : %@",[[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]tokenString]);
                    NSMutableDictionary* parameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
                    [parameters setValue:@"id,name,email,first_name,last_name,picture.type(large)" forKey:@"fields"];
                    [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:parameters]
                     startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                         if (!error) {
                             NSString *fbPhotoUrl = [[[result objectForKey:@"picture"]objectForKey:@"data"]objectForKey:@"url"];
                             lDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
                             [lDefaults setObject:@"fbPhotoUrl" forKey:@"fbPhotoUrl"];
                             [lDefaults synchronize];
                             NSLog(@"%@",fbPhotoUrl);
                         }
                     }];
                }
                else {
                    [self facebookLoginFailed:YES];
                }
            }
        }];
```

if facebook login failed we can write this alert,

```
- (void)facebookLoginFailed:(BOOL)isFBResponce{
if(isFBResponce){
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"pop_attention", nil) message:NSLocalizedString(@"request_error", nil) delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"pop_ok", nil) otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
}
else{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"pop_attention", nil) message:NSLocalizedString(@"loginfb_cancelled", nil) delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"pop_ok", nil) otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
}
}
```

after that goto target-->info-->Url Types-->UrlSchmes(add your facebook id).

and more thing we have to do in www.developers.facebook.com go to ypur app-->under AppReview-->Make YourApp public? as YES.

after that we need to add tis code in plist

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>fb1801381186770425</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>AddYourID</string>
<key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
<string>YourAppName</string>
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>fbapi</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
    <string>fbauth2</string>
    <string>fbshareextension</string>
    <string>instagram</string>
</array>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>To access your current location</string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>To share </string>
```

that's it in Objective-C.

In **Swift** Version

In appdelegate method we need to import this frameworks

```
import FacebookCore
import FacebookLogin
import FBSDKLoginKit
```

after that in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions write

```
FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
```

and call callback method

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, open: url as URL!, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}
```

after that in your viewcontroller import same frameworks after that write thiese lines of code in your facebook login action

```
var dict : [String : AnyObject]!

let fbLoginManager : FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
    fbLoginManager.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["email"], from: self) { (result, error) in
        if (error == nil){
            let fbloginresult : FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult = result!
            if fbloginresult.grantedPermissions != nil {
                if(fbloginresult.grantedPermissions.contains("email")) {
                    self.getFBUserData()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

after that i am getting user data and storing in Dictionary

```
func getFBUserData(){
    if((FBSDKAccessToken.current()) != nil){
        FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email"]).start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in
            if (error == nil){
                self.dict = result as! [String : AnyObject]
                print(result!)
                print(self.dict)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

1.To support login in ios 5 and ios 6 , you can use FBLoginView Class . it is the simplest way to login into facebook using Facebook sdk .

```
    FBLoginView * pFBLoginViewObj = [[FBLoginView alloc] init];
    [pFBLoginViewObj setFrame:self.view.frame];
    pFBLoginViewObj.delegate = self;//optional
    [self.view addSubview:pFBLoginViewObj];
```

implement delegate methods if needed .

2.To maintain session you have to make changes in app dalagate file ....like

```
-(BOOL) application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
    if (url != nil)
    {

        return [[FBSession activeSession] handleOpenURL:url];
    }

    return NO;
}
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{

    [[FBSession activeSession] handleDidBecomeActive];
}
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [[FBSession activeSession] close];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/features/whats-new-ios-sdk-3.1/

Take a look at this Facebook sdk work for both iOS5 and iOS6 as well.